# How to redirect user after he logs in based on his profile

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

after a user logs in, he is redirected to transfer.html. however if user has not created any bank account, i d like to redirect him to createbankaccount.html instead. How do I do that?
Here is my code

```
#login.html
  <form action="." method="post" class="login_form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p class="submit"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">Log in</button></p>
    {% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">{% endif %}
  </form>

#settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/main/'

#urls.py
url(r'^main/$',main_home,name='main_home'),

#views.py
#this is the homepage 
def main_home(request):
    url = '/%s/trans/create' % request.user.username
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

#I want this to be the homepage if user has no bank account
def mybank_add(request):
    url = '/%s/mybank/add' % request.user.username
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `if` yet?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write your own login method that checks a count of any accounts the logged in user has and then redirect to the view you want.

django.contrib.auth provides everything you need as far as forms and methods to authenticate a user, but it's up to you to check the information you need and redirect.

Comment: I disagree.  You could easily have a simple login_router as the settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, which in turn has a simple 'if' statement that redirects the user to one of two places.  No copying of contrib.auth.views.login necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, he could have a landing view with an `if` statement that calls `main_home(request, *args, **kwargs)` if there's a bank account, or `mybank_add(request, *args, **kwargs)` if there isn't.

Comment: @Elf Hmm. I'm not sure I'd go that route because that could result two redirects - first s/he is redirected to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, then redirected to the view if no accounts. Adding your own login method results in only one redirect, which is cleaner design in my opinion.

Comment: The second method requires no second redirect; the switch is internal.  It does mean that the same URL points to two different resources, but maybe our correspondent wants that.

Comment: I can see where you might not have a second redirect, if you're just rendering a different view. I was thinking the view for no accounts would probably be a separate controller action. I think either of the methods we've described will work for the OP.